# How can I slide in a div inside of the container when :hover, and squished specific divs and not others?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have div container with 3 div inside. div 3 is hidden out of the container, on the right side, div 1 is supposed to be in the left of the container (but its width should be as big as possible), and div 2 on the right.

When the container is :hover, I want div 3 to slide in from the right side, push div 2 to the left, and squish div 1 (while div 2 and 3 widths remain stable).

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="div1"></div>
     <div class="div2"></div>
     <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried playing with flex-shrink, flex-basis, with no success. I've tried to put div1 and div2 in a separate div, like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="div4">
     <div class="div1">
       <h3>A title here</h3>
       <p>a description here</p>
     </div>
     <div class="div2">
       <p>text<p>
     </div>
   </div>
     <div class="div3"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 68px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.div4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0px;
  background: yellow;
  flex-shrink: -1;
}

.div1 h3, .div1 p {
  margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.div2 {
  background: red;
      min-width: 68px;
}

.div3 {
    height: 68px;
    min-width: 60px;
    background: #99E2D0;
   position: relative;
    right: -60px;
}

.container:hover > .div3 {
  right: 0px;
}
```

My main issue here is that I'm moving div3 out of the container width right: -60px;, but div4 doesn't stretch to the full width of the container.

Here is the codepen:

https://codepen.io/MaximeZind/pen/KKeeeEb